# how to replace entire row by another row, with the same id, in R?

Tags: r

assuming two dfs:

```
df1:
     name  age  grade
1    john  18    A
2    john  17    A
3    nancy 18    A
4    Jason 16    B

df2:
     name  age  grade
1    john  17    A-
3    nancy 19    A+
```

what I would like to have: replace rows in df1 by row in df2 (if the names are the same), ie.

```
df1:
     name  age  grade
1    john  17    A-
2    john  17    A-
3    nancy 19    A+
4    Jason 16    B
```

Your help is much appreciated !

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use `left_join` and `coalesce`:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(df1, df2, 'name')%>%
  mutate(age = coalesce(age.y, age.x),
         grade = coalesce(grade.y, grade.x))%>%
  select(-contains('.'))

 name age grade
1  john  17    A-
2  john  17    A-
3 nancy  19    A+
4 Jason  16     B
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
rbind(na.omit(cbind(name = df1$name, apply(df2[,names(df1)!= "name"], 2, function(x){
       x[match(df1$name, df2$name)]
      }
    )
  )
), df1[which(df1$name == setdiff(df1$name, df2$name)),])
```

Data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("john", "john", "nancy", "Jason"), age = c(18L, 
17L, 18L, 16L), grade = c("A", "A", "A", "B")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("john", "nancy"), age = c(17L, 19L), 
grade = c("A-", "A+")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score -1):

It is a fairly simple task. I wouldnt use df2 to replace info on df1, but rather use two separate vectors.

```
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("John", "John", "Nancy", "Jason"),
                  age = c(18,17, 18,16),
                  grade = c("A", "A", "A","B"))
df1[1,] <- c("John", 17, "A-")
df1[3,] <- c("Nancy", 19, "A+")

view(df1)
```

Next time you post a question, try to post a reproducible example.

Comment: first, the example posted is reproducible. Second, This is not how to tackle the question. Note that you could have thousands of rows for the data. You cannot do what you just did

Comment: This converts numeric columns to character. Use `list(...)` instead of `c(...)` to safely do this type of replacement.